# What do you call someone who misuses facts (scientific or otherwise) to support their opinions?

Tags: word-request

Basically I'm looking for a word that describes someone who takes facts or things people have said and twists them around to support whatever it is they believe.

The actual scenario: Someone I know is taking scientific facts on our limited knowledge of how the human brain works and is slightly twisting them to support an off the wall theory about how we perceive certain things like animate and inanimate objects.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

You could describe their argument as [inconsequent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inconsequent) as it doesn't follow logically from the known facts.

> characterized by lack of logical sequence; illogical; inconsecutive:

---

You could describe the person as [illogical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illogical) (though maybe that's not specific enough).

> not thinking about things in a reasonable or sensible way

Answer (score 1):

A **pseudoscientist.** Pseudoscience consists of statements, beliefs, or practices that are claimed to be both scientific and factual, but are incompatible with the scientific method ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience)).

A **charlatan** (a **swindler** or **mountebank**) is a person practicing quackery or some similar confidence trick or deception in order to obtain money, fame or other advantages via some form of pretense or deception ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlatan)).

A **quack** is a "fraudulent or ignorant pretender to medical skill" or "a person who pretends, professionally or publicly, to have skill, knowledge, qualification or credentials they do not possess; a charlatan or snake oil salesman" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quackery)).

In the religious context, it is called a **heretic.** Heresy is any belief or theory that is strongly at variance with established beliefs or customs, in particular the accepted beliefs of a church or religious organization. A heretic is a proponent of such claims or beliefs ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heresy)).